# RX Java - observe one side effect on main thread is very slow

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java

I do following in my app (see the comments to see what is happening, logic is quite simple):

```
// 1) import folders from system
importObservable
    // 2) emit all folders as list 
    // => 1 item is emitted only 
    // => flatMap can be used for sequential execution
    .toList()
    // 3) Log current time
    .doOnNext(data -> T.start(KEY_TIME_LOGGER))
    // 4) throw away data from import
    // load all data from database now in an empty state 
    // => 1 item is emitted only
    .flatMap(data -> loadFoldersEmpty())
    // 5) Log time
    .doOnNext(data -> L.d("Folder - 1 - empty list created: " + T.printTotalAndLap(KEY_TIME_LOGGER)))
    // 6) observe the list of folders on the main thread
    // because we will update the UI
    // => 1 emitted item only
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext(items -> onNextItemAvailable(items))
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    // 7) Log time
    .doOnNext(data -> L.d("Folder - 2 - empty data delivered: " + T.printTotalAndLap(KEY_TIME_LOGGER)))
    // 8) loading full folders 
    // => this emits multiple items, folder per folder
    .flatMap(data -> loadFullFolders(data)) 
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                onLoadingFinished();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                onLoadingError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) {
                onNextItemAvailable(o);
            }
        });
```

The problem is, what happens after comment #6 is quite slow (something about 200ms to 300ms). Is there a better way to have side effects on the main thread?

Comment: Did you happen to find the reason? I came here in search for an elegant way to show/hide "loading" progress before and after the work-horse operation.